# Как с помощью .htaccess заменить символы

Tags: .htaccess

В .htaccess у меня прописано так

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^chapter/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?chapter=$1&page=$2 [L]`

Сейчас путь вот такой http://site/?chapter=php&page=9.

Ожидаю вот таким  http://site/chapter/php/9  Но  не изменяется.

Comment: `Ожидаю вот таким` не надо этого ожидать. Такие ссылки должен формировать движок вашего сайта на страницах отдаваемых посетителю, а не .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^chapter=(\w+)&page=(\d+)$
RewriteRule .* /chapter/%1/%2? [R]
```